# Existence of $\omega$ ($\aleph_0$)

Tags: ordinals

We have by definition $\omega = \aleph_0$ both are countable ie., successor of an integer, but $\omega$ is also limit ie., $\models (\alpha \neq 0 \wedge (\forall\beta(\beta+1 \neq \alpha)))$. Do not "countable" and "limit" contradict each other ?

Comment: Are you asking for a proof there is a transfinite ordinal? Zermelo set theory and descendants such as ZF and ZFC take this as axiomatic.

Comment: "both are countable ie., successor of an integer". What does this even mean?

Comment: Your use of the $\models$ symbol is incorrect. It would be better if you avoided symbols if using them may be confusing, as in this case.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo "is limit" ie., satisfy the sentence. What is wrong here ?

Comment: "What is wrong here ?" The way the symbols are being used.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Please explain what should be the proper way.

Comment: @AlexKruckman What "What does this even mean" mean ?

Comment: I just meant that what you wrote doesn't make any sense. If what you mean is "$\omega$ is countable, so it is the successor of an integer", this is totally wrong. "countable" does not mean "is a successor of an integer".

Comment: @AlexKruckman Doesn't "countable" mean "has an injection onto $\mathbb N$" and isn't any integer the successor of another integer ?

Comment: @Soleil Sure, both those things are true. But what's the connection? $\omega$ has an injection into $\mathbb{N}$ (careful with the word *onto*: it is usually used as a synonym for "surjective"). It does not follow that $\omega$ is an integer.

Comment: The set $\{1, 42, 1000\}$ has an injection into $\mathbb{N}$. Is the set $\{1,42,1000\}$ an integer?

Comment: @AlexKruckman You make a point. Thanks for the details.

Answer (score 2):

When we say that $\omega$ is countable, what we mean is that there exists an injection $\omega\to\mathbb N$, not that it's the successor of some integer. This is certainly not the case, since as you had previously said, $\omega$ is in fact a limit ordinal. So, there's no contradiction, you just messed up the terminology somewhat.

Comment: Is not any integer the successor of another integer ?

Comment: $\omega$ isn’t really an integer. It’s defined as the first ordinal greater than all integers: this is possible to do since ordinals and integers are two distinct concepts. You might want to read up on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number).

Comment: If $\omega \to \mathbb N$ then $\omega$ has a corresponding integer. Any integer is an ordinal, but not all ordinals are integers.

Comment: Every element of $\omega$ is an integer, but that doesn’t make it an integer.

Comment: @Soleil: Every element of $\{\varnothing\}$ is empty, but $\{\varnothing\}$ is not empty.